# If click button StopPropagation button parent row click

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, stoppropagation

My problem is when I click my button it does not appear my button click it appears my row click (collapse event).

I have two button here one is for open modal and another have onclick event but it doesn't work.It's open row collapse event.

My modal open button is Cevapla.Sil button is deleting the message but it is only collapsing the panel under row

[image: Image of my table]

Here is my html :

```
<tr class='accordion-toggle'  onclick='UpdateIsRead(this);' style='cursor:pointer;background-color:{6}' data-toggle='collapse' data-target='#gelenRow{0}' data-isread='{5}'>
   <td class='email-title'>{1}
   </td>
   <td class='email-body'>{2}
   </td>
   <td>{3}
   </td>
   <td>
      <a class='modalButton btn btn-info btn-xs' data-height='550' title='Cevap Yaz' data-src='{7}apps/pages/PrivateMessage.aspx?topic={8}&toWho={9}' data-title='Cevap Yaz' data-headericoncolor='#000000' data-headercolor='#000000' data-icon='fa fa-envelope' data-toggle='modal' style='cursor: pointer' data-target='#popup' style='height:28px'><span class='fa fa-edit'></span> Cevapla</a>            
      <a style='height:28px' onclick='DeleteMessage();'  title='Sil'  class='btn btn-danger btn-xs'><span class='fa fa-remove'></span> Sil</a>
   </td>
</tr>
<tr id='gelenRow{0}' class='collapse' style='background-color:#F5F5F5'>
   <td colspan='6'>
      <div class='panel-footer' style='padding: 10px 35px;'>
         <div class='row'>
            <div id='filter-panel' class='filter-panel'>
               <div class='panel panel-default'>
                  <div class='panel-body'>
                     {4}
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <button type='button' class='btn btn-sm btn-primary' >Cevap Yaz</button>
         </div>
      </div>
   </td>
</tr>
```

And I try this code :

```
$(document).on("click","tr", function(e){
    if (e.target.nodeName == "A" || e.target.nodeName == "SPAN") {
        e.parent().stopPropagation();
    }
});

$(document).on("click","tr", function(e){
    if (e.target.nodeName == "A" || e.target.nodeName == "SPAN") {
        e.stopPropagation();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Because your **DeleteMessage & UpdateIsRead** functions are inline in the HTML you can consider to pass the current element and event:

```
<tr class='accordion-toggle'  onclick='UpdateIsRead(this, event);'
```

In this way you can add a test in your functions to stop propagation or action.

The event handlers order, clicking on DeleteMessage button is:

- DeleteMessage
- UpdateIsRead
- $(document).on("click", "tr",...

```js
function UpdateIsRead(ele, e) {
    console.log('UpdateIsRead');
    if (e.target.nodeName == "A" || e.target.nodeName == "SPAN") {
        //e.stopPropagation();
    }
}
function DeleteMessage(ele, e) {
    console.log('DeleteMessage');
    if (e.target.nodeName == "A" || e.target.nodeName == "SPAN") {
        //e.stopPropagation();
    }
}
$(document).on("click", "tr", function(e){
    console.log('$(document).on("click", "tr"...');
    if (e.target.nodeName == "A" || e.target.nodeName == "SPAN") {
        e.stopPropagation();
    }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<table class="table table-striped">
    <tbody>
    <tr class='accordion-toggle'  onclick='UpdateIsRead(this, event);' style='cursor:pointer;background-color:{6}' data-toggle='collapse' data-target='#gelenRow0' data-isread='{5}'>
        <td class='email-title'>{1}
        </td>
        <td class='email-body'>{2}
        </td>
        <td>{3}
        </td>
        <td>
            <a class='modalButton btn btn-info btn-xs' data-height='550' title='Cevap Yaz' data-src='{7}apps/pages/PrivateMessage.aspx?topic={8}&toWho={9}' data-title='Cevap Yaz' data-headericoncolor='#000000' data-headercolor='#000000' data-icon='fa fa-envelope' data-toggle='modal' style='cursor: pointer' data-target='#popup' style='height:28px'><span class='fa fa-edit'></span> Cevapla</a>
            <a style='height:28px' onclick='DeleteMessage(this, event);'  title='Sil'  class='btn btn-danger btn-xs'><span class='fa fa-remove'></span> Sil</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id='gelenRow0' class='collapse' style='background-color:#F5F5F5'>
        <td colspan='6'>
            <div class='panel-footer' style='padding: 10px 35px;'>
                <div class='row'>
                    <div id='filter-panel' class='filter-panel'>
                        <div class='panel panel-default'>
                            <div class='panel-body'>
                                {4}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <button type='button' class='btn btn-sm btn-primary' >Cevap Yaz</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: my  $('a.modalButton').on('click', function (e) {  doesnt work now when I click button .But this works  $(document).on("click", "a.modalButton", function(e){});  why?

Comment: Because it's a delegated event. The modal button doesn't exist now but in future. That's why it works delegating to document.